# Custom E-Mail-Notification on data changes

Tags: oracle, database-design, push-notification

I want to develop a component which send E-Mail-Notifications when a specific or unspecific record has changed.

I want the user to select a table and maybe a specific column or row. Then I want to notify the user when something from his selection changed.

I use a Oracle 12g Database.

Is there a common way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

I already tried the following techniques:

- Oracle Continuous Query Notification
- Oracle Change Data Capture
- Oracle Triggers

Example:

1. The user "subscribes" the table "customer" and the column "street".
2. When a value in the column "street" ist updated, inserted or deleted, the user receives an E-Mail.

Comment: What happens if the user issues a `ROLLBACK` command? The e-mail would be sent already in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the user to select a table and maybe a specific column or row.

I want to start my answer with *"obviously"* but I guess it may not be obvious. Either way, there is no common or generic way of doing this. It is not a common requirement, and when this sort of thing is required CQN usually satisfies. However, you have ruled out CQN (without giving reasons why it doesn't suit your needs). I suppose it's because CQN doesn't allow a user to specify and implement a policy through an interface.

That being the case there are not many options for you. In fact the only one which occurs to me is a tool to generate compound triggers through Dynamic SQL. You need triggers because that's easy way to track the sort of things you want to track. You want compound triggers so you can evaluate multiple rows but only send one email per DML statement. You want a generator because dynamic SQL is the only way to build triggers fitted to user-defined criteria.

Executing triggers is a performance issue. So, two things you need to handle:

- what happens when one user wants to track multiple different events on the same table?
- what happens when multiple users want to track the same event (or different events!) on the same table?

There's a lot of complexity here. You really should assess just how important this requirement is and just how much flexibility your users really need before you go too far down this rabbit hole.

Comment: Thank you very much for your evaluation. It's not that CQN doesn't fit my needs, it does. I was just wondering wether there is a common way to do this.
But as you said, there "obviously" seems to be no way.